# Set Type of OCaml List

Tags: list, ocaml

I want to set the type of a list to be ints but I have no idea of how to do this.
I can do the following:

```
let listOfInts = [];
```

But that just makes listOfInts be a list with any type allowed to be put in to it.
How can I force the listOfInts to only be a list of ints?

This is for making a dictionary in OCaml which maps a string (key) to an int (value).
For simplicity, I am just going to have the value be the length of the string.
Could someone help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declare the type explicitly.

```
let (listOfInts : int list) = [];
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no use in forcing the type through an annotation here: you can use `[]` at any type but, as soon as you use it to create list of elements of a specific type, it will be instantiated to the right type.

Having annotations is occasionally useful for types of values with mutable state that are neither fully inferred nor generalized (eg `ref []`).

I don't see how this relates to you wider question of having a map between strings and ints, as this does not involve lists at all. If you want a mutable map you can use [Hasthbl](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Hashtbl.html), otherwise [Map](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Map.html).

```
module StringMap = Map.Make(String)
let m = StringMap.add "foo" 3 StringMap.empty
```

(`m` has type `int StringMap.t`)